# Девочка для битья

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, фразеология, стилистика

Услышал только что, как женщина на улице кому-то говорила по телефону, мол, *то да сё, как будто я **девочка** для битья.*

Можно женщинам делать такую замену или всё равно даже они должны говорить "мальчик"?

Answer (score 2):

Заглянем в словари.

**Мальчик для битья** — 1. мальчик, которого наказывали, когда принц плохо себя вёл или плохо учился; 2. тот, кого заставляют расплачиваться за чужую вину (переносное значение); см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F+%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F).

Как видно, у этого словосочетания есть два значения: исторический термин и устойчивое выражение. Если первое мы "подстроить" под себя вряд ли  можем без уточнений, так как понятие фактическое, вошедшее в речь только в таком виде как термин, то второе как раз таки можем: переносное значение это позволяет. Вспомните, например, сколько пословиц и поговорок мы слышим и употребляем в изменённом, сокращённом варианте, опуская вторую часть выражения:

- где тонко, там и рвётся, [*где толсто, там и наслаивается*];
- аппетит приходит во время еды, [*а жадность – во время аппетита*];
- ума палата, [*да ключ потерян*] и т. д.

Так что на практике искажение устойчивых выражений — явление нередкое, и вы можете точно так же их изменять. Более того, конкретно выражение "девочка для битья" встречается в литературе — и не раз. Приведу лишь несколько примеров.

*Нельзя показывать сомнение, или всегда будешь **девочкой для битья**. [Мария Дубинина, Школа заклинателей. Призывающая, 2020]*

*Со временем она стала раздражать царя, и он пользовался любым предлогом, чтобы досадить ей, превратив её буквально в **девочку для битья**. [Олег Рясков, Записки экспедитора Тайной канцелярии. К берегам Новой Англии, 2011]*

*Но на этот раз я не собиралась выступать в роли **девочки для битья**. [Ирина Градова, Врач от бога, 2010]*

**ВЫВОД**

Заменить "мальчика" на "девочку" можно — на усмотрение автора: скажем, это уместно, когда выражение употребляется по отношению к персонажу женского пола. В вашем случае так оно и есть, поэтому замена оправданна.

*То да сё, как будто я **девочка для битья**.*

Comment: Спасибо! Вот только примеры у вас все очень современные, до классиков ух как далеко!

Comment: Более старых не нашёл, но оно и понятно: подстраивать это выражение под пол стали, видимо, недавно. Равенство полов и всё такое...